# error: c++ [map] does not name a type

Tags: c++, parsing, dictionary, enums

I've written the following as part of a text command parser for a text adventure game.

I'm attempting to associate a string input by a user to an item in an enum class. The following is in my header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

enum class Noun
{
    // Interrogation subjects
    name,                   // ask the subject his name
    base,                   // where is the base?
    attack,                 // when will the attack be?

    invalid
};

map < string, Noun > knownNouns;
knownNouns["name"]      = Noun::name;
knownNouns["base"]      = Noun::base;
knownNouns["attack"]    = Noun::attack;

Noun parseNoun(string &noun)
{
    auto n = knownNouns.find(noun);
    if ( n == knownNouns.end() ) {
        return Noun::invalid;
    }
    return n->second;
```

When I put this through the compiler, I get the following:

```
nouns.h:46:1: error: 'knownNouns' does not name a type
 knownNouns["name"]      = Noun::name;
 ^
nouns.h:47:1: error: 'knownNouns' does not name a type
 knownNouns["base"]      = Noun::base;
 ^
nouns.h:48:1: error: 'knownNouns' does not name a type
 knownNouns["attack"]    = Noun::attack;
 ^
nouns.h: In function 'Noun parseNoun(std::string&)':
nouns.h:52:10: error: 'n' does not name a type
     auto n = knownNouns.find(noun);
          ^
nouns.h:53:10: error: 'n' was not declared in this scope
     if ( n == knownNouns.end() ) {
          ^
nouns.h:54:16: error: 'Noun' is not a class or namespace
         return Noun::invalid;
                ^
nouns.h:56:12: error: 'n' was not declared in this scope
     return n->second;
            ^
```

This is my first time attempting to use maps and enums, and I'm not sure what it is I did wrong. I'm also not *terribly* familiar with the use of auto vars, so that's a bit of cargo-cult programming on my part. I'm hoping I understood its implementation and the error will clear once I resolve the type definition problem I'm having.

edit: That's embarassing. I copy pasted a mistake that I had already corrected. the code still does not compile when (i.e., the same issue occurs when)

```
map < string, Noun > knownNouns;
knownNouns["name"]      = Verb::name;
knownNouns["base"]      = Verb::base;
knownNouns["attack"]    = Verb::attack;
```

is corrected as

```
map < string, Noun > knownNouns;
knownNouns["name"]      = Noun::name;
knownNouns["base"]      = Noun::base;
knownNouns["attack"]    = Noun::attack;
```

Comment: You have to put your assignments inside a function.

Comment: I have compiled it in a c++11 compiler, yes.

Comment: Galik, I'm looking for an example of what you mean. Is there a possibility you know of a good example of constructing it in the way you described?

Comment: See @Oncaphillis's answer for what I mean. Those lines have to be inside a function.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't place non-declaration constructs directly in namespace scope.

A C++ translation unit is a sequence of declarations.

Non-declaration statements such as assignments must be inside function bodies.

---

Fixed code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

enum class Noun
{
    // Interrogation subjects
    name,                   // ask the subject his name
    base,                   // where is the base?
    attack,                 // when will the attack be?

    invalid
};

map< string, Noun > knownNouns = 
{
    { "name", Noun::name },
    { "base", Noun::base },
    { "attack", Noun::attack }
};

auto parseNoun( string const& noun )
    -> Noun
{
    // auto n = knownNouns.find(noun);
    // if ( n == knownNouns.end() ) {
        // return Noun::invalid;
    // }
    // return n->second;
    return Noun::invalid;
}
```

Here `knownNouns` is *initialized*. It's not an assignment, even if the `=` looks very much like an assignment.

Comment: Is there any reason for your transformation to trailing-return-type notation?

Comment: Yes. We won't get people to adopt the notation nearly as fast if don't actively show the way and familiarize people with it.

Comment: Well, that's a worthy goal, though I'll personally stick to only using it where it provides some more tangible benefits.

Comment: The error I get after implementing your changes is:

 verbs.h:23:1: warning: scoped enums only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
  enum class Verb
  ^
 verbs.h:35:21: error: 'Verb' is not a class or namespace
   {   "ask",      Verb::ask     },
       ^
 verbs.h:36:21: error: 'Verb' is not a class or namespace
   {   "quit",     Verb::quit    },
       ^
 verbs.h:37:21: error: 'Verb' is not a class or namespace
   {   "exit",     Verb::quit    }
       ^
 verbs.h:38:1: error: in C++98 'knownVerbs' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'
  };
  ^

Comment: It doesn't make a whole lot of sense, because there the class Verb is, right above it...

edit: I am using a c++11 compiler

Comment: @BradleyEvans: add option `-std=c++11` as the compiler suggests (telling it that this is C++11 code). you may also want to add `-Wall`, `-Wextra` and `-pedantic-errors`. IIRC. ;-) Note that there is no name `Verb` in the fixed code in this answer. So that's not the code that you're compiling.

Comment: Can I get clarification on what it was you were doing where another user described "trailing return type notation"?

Comment: This is a late reply to this but I noticed that this question was getting views. I thought I'd clarify that this did indeed solve my problem at the time.

Comment: What would you do in C++98? Don't ask why, but I need to write C++98 and this {...} syntax throws an error there.

Comment: @Nobody: In C++98 you can place the initialization data in a raw array. Then use the constructor taking iterators. It's just more roundabout.

Answer (score 3):

You may not initialize map entries statically like:

```
 knownNouns["name"]      = Verb::name;
 knownNouns["base"]      = Verb::base;
 knownNouns["attack"]    = Verb::attack;
```